# Ability to quickly add items to custom post type

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, taxonomy

Is there the ability to quickly add items to a custom post type in WordPress? 
I want to be able to add multiple short items (client id, article, id, price) to a custom post type at once, like the function of the ACF Repeater fields.
[image]

So basically a "+" button underneath these 3 fields to add another set of 3 fields so you can add multiple products at the same time.
Is there a plugin for this or any other option?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your custom post type supports custom fields this is build into wordpress. In your post edit screen click the 'Screen Options' tab in the top right under the 'Howdy' menu. Check the 'Custom Fields' checkbox and you'll see a new meta box below the post body.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not quite what I'm looking for. I am looking for an option to create multiple posts on one page, so that I do not have to individually go to create post, save, back, create post, etc.

Comment: I'd give this a try [link](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/expand-the-wordpress-quick-edit-menu) You'd still have to create each post but you could manage all the meta data in the quick edit screen. Should save some time. Otherwise I think you're looking at something major to add multiple posts from a singel edit screen. Maybe start a bounty?

Comment: I've decided to steer away from the custom post types and instead will use a PHP form on the website to add multiple rows of data to a db